# Programmatical counting of data

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have an sqlite3 database from which I need to get data from, then programmatically count the amount of data per id. I shouldn't use database queries.

Comment: That is very nice, what is your question though?

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment - why else the "no database queries" restriction?

Answer (score 0):

You can load the sqlite3 table to pandas directly using `pd.read_sql()` function. Then you can use the `groupby` function from pandas library to group by id, and then use `.count()` to get the count per id.